# if $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{a_{n}} x^{n} d x=2,a_n>0,$find $ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n$

Tags: limits

if $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{a_{n}} x^{n} d x=2,a_n>0,$$find $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n$$

what I did is this :

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{a_{n}} x^{n} d x&=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} a_{n}^{n+1}=2 \Rightarrow a_{n}^{n+1} \rightarrow \infty\\
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}&=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(2(n+1))^{\frac{1}{n+1}}=e^{\frac{1}{n+1} \ln (2(n+1))}=1?
\end{aligned}$$

Am I right? I don't have answer.

I think I was wrong , because  my method always get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=1$, no matter the integral equals any other number ,

Comment: I dont really get where the first equality on the last row comes from

Comment: Entirely correct. The convergence of the integrals to some $k>0$ implies that $a_n\to 1$.  And if $k>0$ and $a_n=(k(n+1))^{1/(n+1)}$ then the integrals converge to $k$. That is, for any $k>0$ there is a sequence $a_n\to 1$ that causes the integrals to converge to $k$... There are also many sequences $a_n\to 1$ such  that the integrals don't converge.

Comment: @GradaGukovic . For all but finitely many $n\in \Bbb N$ we have  $1<(a_n)^{n+1}/(n+1)<3, $ & this inequality implies  $(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}<a_n< (3(n+1))^{1/(n+1)}.$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L\gt1$ then there exists $N\gt0$ such that $\forall n\gt N$, $a_n\gt \frac{L+1}{2}\gt1$. Hence we have that
$$\int_0^{a_n}x^n\mathrm{d}x\gt\int_0^{(L+1)/2}x^n\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{L+1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\to\infty$$
Similarly suppose that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=M\lt1$ then there exists $N\gt0$ such that $\forall n\gt N$, $a_n\lt \frac{M+1}{2}\lt1$. Hence we have that
$$\int_0^{a_n}x^n\mathrm{d}x\lt\int_0^{(M+1)/2}x^n\mathrm{d}x=\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{M+1}{2}\right)^{n+1}\to0$$
So if the limit in question tends to $2$ then we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$ otherwise the limit is either $0$ or diverges.

Answer (score 1):

You have seen that $\frac {a_n^{n+1}} {n+1} \to 2$. This gives $(n+1) \ln a_n-\ln (n+1) \to ln \, 2$. Divide by $n+1$ and take limit. You get $\ln a_n \to 0$ and hence $a_n \to 1$.

[$\frac {ln (n+1)} {n+1} \to 0$ by L'Hopital's Rule].

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct

Note that $$\lim _{n\to \infty}a^{1/{(n+1)}}=1 $$ for any positive value of $a$

Thus if you change the value of the integral from $2$ to any other positive integer the limit does not change.